# compare-and-set! to unconditionally reset an atom in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Consider the following sequence of code in the clojure repl

```
(def elems (atom {}))
(swap! elems assoc 42 [:a 7])
elems
```

producing the expected `{42 [:a 7]}`. Now try

```
(compare-and-set! elems elems (atom {}))
```

producing `false`, meaning the `compare-and-set!` operation did not succeed.  I am surprised, because I expected `elems` to test identical to `elems` inside the `compare-and-set!` operations.  I am aware that I can use `reset!` to accomplish the goal of unconditionally reset the atom, but I want to know why `compare-and-set!` doesn't do exactly the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`compare-and-set!` works on values referenced by atoms, not on atoms themselves.

```
clojure.core/compare-and-set!
([atom oldval newval])
  Atomically sets the value of atom to newval if and only if the
  current value of the atom is identical to oldval. Returns true if
  set happened, else false
```

You probably want this:

```
(compare-and-set! elems @elems {})
```